# Do the following extra highlighted words in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit prevent us from concluding that the limit exists? Why? Why not?

Tags: limits, physics, mathematical-physics, epsilon-delta, potential-theory

This question consists of two parts: preliminary and the main question. Reading only the main question may be enough to get my point, but if you want details please have a look at the preliminary.

**PRELIMINARY:**

Let potential due to a small volume $\delta$ at a point $(1,2,3)$ inside it be denoted by $\psi_{\delta}$.

[image]

---

*It can be shown* that for every $\epsilon>0$, we can choose a volume $\delta$ such that:

$\left|    \dfrac{\psi_{\delta}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{\delta}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}   \right|  < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} \tag1$

That is $\epsilon$ can be made as small as we can by choosing a small volume $\delta$.

---

Also, using spherical coordinate system we can show that for every $\epsilon>0$, we can choose a volume $\delta$ such that:

$\displaystyle\left|  \iiint_{\delta}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV' \right|  < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$

That is:

$\displaystyle\left|  \iiint_{V'}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV'
-\iiint_{(V'-\delta)}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV' \right|  < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} \tag2$

That is $\epsilon$ can be made as small as we can by choosing a small volume $\delta$.

---

No matter what our volume $\delta$ is, at point $P(1,2,3)$, $\dfrac{\partial \psi_{(V'-\delta)}}{\partial x}$ exists (since  $P$ being an outside point of $V'-\delta$). That is:

$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{\partial \psi_{(V'-\delta)}}{\partial x} (1,2,3)$

That is, for every $\epsilon>0$, we can choose an interval $\delta x$ around $\Delta x = 0$ (inside volume $\delta$) such that whenever $0 < |\Delta x-0| < \delta x$:

$\left|    \dfrac{\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}  - \dfrac{\partial \psi_{(V'-\delta)}}{\partial x} (1,2,3)  \right|  < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$

That is:

$\left|    \dfrac{\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{(V'-\delta)}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}  -   \left(    -\displaystyle\iiint_{(V'-\delta)}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV'   \right)    \right|  < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} \tag3$

That is $\epsilon$ can be made as small as we can by choosing a small interval $\delta x$ around $\Delta x = 0$ (inside volume $\delta$)

---

Adding inequalities $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$:

$\left|    \dfrac{\psi_{V'}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{V'}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}  -   \left(    -\displaystyle \iiint_{V'}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV'   \right)    \right|  < \epsilon$

That is, for every $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $\bbox[yellow]{\text{a volume $\delta$ and}}$ an interval $\delta x$ around $\Delta x = 0$ (inside volume $\delta$) such that whenever $0 < |\Delta x-0| < \delta x$, the above inequality holds.

That is, $\epsilon$ can be made as small as we can by choosing $\bbox[yellow]{\text{a small volume $\delta$ and}}$ a small interval $\delta x$ around $\Delta x = 0$ (inside volume $\delta$)

> **QUESTION:**
>
> **Since there are some extra highlighted words in the above $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, will this prevent us from saying that:**
>
> $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\psi_{V'}(1+\Delta x,2,3)-\psi_{V'}(1,2,3)}{\Delta x}=-\displaystyle \iiint_{V'}  \dfrac{\rho'}{R^2}  \dfrac{x-x'}{R} dV'$
>
> **? Why? Why not?**